# FOSS-base AVR ISP programming with USB

Tags: usb, avr, isp, open-source

I've been using a free software stack for AVR programming - AVR GCC + avrdude on Linux, with parallel DIY programmer cable.

Since the parallel bitbang programmer doesn't work with USB printer cables, I'm stuck with using my desktop PC.

Is there an USB-based programmer that can be supported by a free-software (command-line based) programming tool?

Comment: Unless you need odd target voltages an Arduino running the Arduino-as-ISP sketch can do this.  Technically "is there a product..." or "is there a piece of code..." questions are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

[avrdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) supports a wide range of programming devices, including:

- Atmel's first-party programmers, including the [STK500](http://www.atmel.com/tools/stk500.aspx), [STK600](http://www.atmel.com/tools/stk600.aspx), [JTAG ICE](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRJTAGICEMKII.aspx) and [AVR Dragon](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRDRAGON.aspx).
- The [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) and [USBtinyISP](https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp), and clones thereof -- both of which are available inexpensively online
- Devices which include an FTDI FT232/FT2232/FT4232 (not FT232R) USB interface
- The [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate), which can be handy for other things too
- Arduino devices -- either to program the Arduino itself, or to program another device
- GPIOs on embedded devices (like the Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 1):

I use an USBASP 2.0 clone for programming atMega328 (uno's and the like), works like a charm. And dirt cheap from the well-known Chinese sources.

Answer (score 0):

I own an USBtiny I can recommend:

https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp/overview